# add custom header in term listing tpl page

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I want to add some header information in header of term listing. This is my requirement. 
[image]

I achieve the listing of terms (store) with the help of **term-taxonomy--store.tpl.php** template but how to add **Find stores alphabetically** portion in header, because if I add that portion in **term-taxonomy--store.tpl.php** , it repeats with every store. what i have to do for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not trying to do that in the right place. The data manipulations should be made (in my opinion) in the modules part or in your template.php, not in your files.tpl.php...

If I were you, I'd proceed with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module that allows exactly to do what you're trying to get. Answers to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25030/create-alphabetical-pager) could help you to create an alphabetical pager with Views.